# Could windows forms/wpf (not hardware accelerated) handle this?

Tags: wpf, winforms

I've created this charting tool in XNA that visualizes data and lets me interact with it (zooming in and out and moving back and forward in time). Anyway, I was simply wondering if I should stick with XNA or if windows forms could handle this sort of live interaction and this much data?

I don't know what more to provide, hopefully the screenshot is enough for general guidelines. Thanks in advance!
[image: chart image]

Comment: What does non-hardware accelerated mean?

Comment: I mean not using the gpu. As I understand it, windows forms and wpf do not use the gpu. I've changed the title.

Comment: Every pixel you see on your screen is handled by the GPU. I must go a long way back memory lane to come up with a computer that doesn't use separate video processor. Maybe a zx-spectrum didn't have one...

Comment: Are you being stupid? You could be more helpful. We aren't playing top notch 3d games through windows forms now are we? So obviously that is what I mean, not hardware accelerated, or not as well hardware accelerated, whatever. Bla bla bla, wpf uses the cpu much more, end of story. Sorry I don't know all the terms after having programmed for mere 4 months.

Comment: Sorry though, I'm being a bit unfair. Its just that I had searched online and somehow got to the conclusion that wpf is software accelerated instead of hardware accelerated. But maybe thats incorrect, but in any case, those are the terms used online.

Comment: It doesn't work that way. The video system is abstracted away from the OS and therefore from .Net. If you use win32 api to draw a pixel it is up to video driver that comes with the video card to decide how to handle that. It can be highly accelerated or not accelerated at all. Never the less, I expect either winforms or wpf to be able to do what you want IF your algorithms to fetch/calculate the data points and draw them are OK.

Comment: Alright thanks, I'll read further into this.

Comment: How big is your dataset?

Comment: It can be millions of elements. But that's what I seem to do different from others. I only fetch the data needed for what I'm viewing at the moment and then when I scroll around it will change the range of elements I need. In any case though, I'm not using more than 1 array element per pixel (width).

Comment: That will work on winforms or wpf on an up-to-date system. Your approach is sound.

Comment: And the calculation for that is really simple. There are 2 values, the starting array position and amount of elements to look back. So when I zoom in/out, the lookback amount changes (amount of elements to fit to screen) and when I move forward/backwards in time the array index starting position changes.

Comment: @rene I have been trying this now and I am getting massive flickering / late drawing. It takes many many many cycles for it to simply draw everything once. Which means massive flickering, and if one would wait for it to draw everything before updating, then super low fps. Not 60fps, not 30fps, or anything even lower. Nothing that can be interactive at all. I've chosen to go with opengl through c#. I really don't understand at all how this is supposed to be possible, people are having massive problems with flickering on much lower demanding projects than mine.

Answer (score 2):

I think that WPF should probably be able to handle this but you said yourself that it was already created in XNA. You should weigh up the drawbacks of having it in XNA rather with the drawbacks of porting it to WPF. I suppose that it really depends on the CPU. Rather than using native tools you could draw it manually with a .NET openGL equivalent meaning you can take advantage of more than 1 core